# Time derivative of a function involving absolute value

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-derivative, absolute-value

I have a functional looking like this $$ L[u] = \int \int_{\Omega} k \left| \nabla u \right|^2$$ , for which I want to take the time derivative $\dot{L}$. I am not sure that I handled the time derivation of the absolute function correctly, I did it this way -
$$\dot{L}[u] = \int \int_{\Omega} k \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left| \nabla u \right|^2 = \int \int_{\Omega} 2k \left| \nabla u \right| \left|\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \nabla u \right|= \int \int_{\Omega} 2k \left| \nabla u \right| \left|\nabla\frac{\partial}{\partial t}  u \right|$$
Any math expert can confirm that I am doing the right thing here?

Comment: $\left|\nabla u\right|^2 = \nabla u \cdot \nabla u$ and $\cdot$ is bilinear.

Comment: Meaning that I can write $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left| \nabla u \right|^2 = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\nabla u \cdot \nabla u) = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\nabla u \right)\cdot \nabla u + \nabla u  \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\nabla u \right)$ ?